# How can I change Integer.parseInt() for decimal number?

Tags: android

```
    public void showLoanPayments(View clickedButton) {

        double loanAmount = Integer.(mLoanAmount.getText().toString());
        double interestRate = (Integer.parseInt(mInterestRate.getText().toString()));
        double loanPeriod = Integer.parseInt(mLoanPeriod.getText().toString());
        double r = interestRate/1200;
        double r1 = Math.pow(r+1,loanPeriod);

        double monthlyPayment = (double) ((r+(r/(r1-1))) * loanAmount);
        double totalPayment = monthlyPayment * loanPeriod;

        mMonthlyPaymentResult.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(monthlyPayment));
        mTotalPaymentsResult.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(totalPayment));
    }
}
```

Comment: post your answer if you solved the problem so that the remaining people will be benefited.

Answer (score 0):

who just now post the answer? Thanks for that because I already solve the problem.  Thanks again.